# RStudio: git add --all from the UI

Tags: r, git, rstudio

I would like to understand if I am missing anything here, and if not, this is a feature request for RStudio.

I was wondering if there is an option to add all untracked files to the index, and/or to commit all changed files, through the UI, without having to go through the shell, or without having to individually check all the boxes.

[image]

As in the image, I have created two new files, and would like to stage both of them in one go, exactly akin to `git add --all`. Is there a way to do this from the UI without going through the shell.

Comment: I am also interested in this. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Please visit  following websites. (1) http://www.r-bloggers.com/rstudio-and-github/  (2) https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532077-Version-Control-with-Git-and-SVN (3) https://jennybc.github.io/2014-05-12-ubc/ubc-r/session03_git.html .Hope this can help you-

Comment: i dont think you read the question. op knows how to use git. op knows how to use rstudio. op knows how to use rstudio + git. the question is actually very specific and clear @Md.SahidulIslam

Answer (score 38):

If you want to check all the boxes, while having the focus on one of the files as shown in the picture, you can simply press `Ctrl + A` and then `Enter`/`Space` or `Cmd + A` then `Enter`/`Space`. That will first select all boxes and then check them (or uncheck if checked).

Then you will have to write the commit message an click commit of course.

I am using RStudio Version 0.99.486

Answer (score 0):

For my experience, just check the checkbox of the files inside git frame, and then push file, commit (the files will only push to branch but not master) and push again(push to master repo). And you can delete a file call index.lock.init if you cannot check the checkbox. Hope this helps.